# Webview is not displaying table properly in 4.0+ in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using the following code to display content in webview.

```
    mMessageContentView.setText(emailText, contentType);
    mMessageContentView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    mMessageContentView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mMessageContentView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It is displaying properly in nexus one,samsung player etc,but it is not displaying in Samsung s2(4.0.1),Samsung Nexus(4.2.1)

Here i am attaching the Screen shots of both(Nexus one,Google nexus)[image: Google Nexus]).[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I observed that , In some devices like Samsung Galaxy S2,S3 etc Webview displays the Table in a single column. So i applied the following code to chage the Webview Table setting as Normal.

```
    mMessageContentView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

Then it is displaying in Correct format in all the devices.

Comment: webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL); is not working in showing highlighted text which isusing html bdo tag to highlight. When i set setLayoutAlgorithm, my highlighted text arranged using css column property is breaking and some texts are missing. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the raw HTML from the table? It is impossible to know what is right and wrong without that.

You can also check how it renders in a recent version of Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I am getting that HTML file from server.just i am displaying in webview.in Nexus one the table is coming fine.But in samgung galaxy S2,S3 it is not coming fine.

Comment: In some Devices Like Samsung Galaxy S2,S3 etc,Webview is Diapying the Table in Single Column fromat.so i changed the Format By using the Following code.

Comment: It's still display as single column in Android 6 :(